# tensorflow merge input and output

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow

I would like to use two model in tensorflow in a row, to fit the first one and to use directly it for the second one as input. But I didn't find the good way to do it. I tried to proceed as the following ,

```
x = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, image_size[0] , image_size[1]])

y1_ = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, image_size[0] , image_size[1], 1])
y2_ = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, image_size[0] , image_size[1],\ 
                                                               labels_count])
image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,image_size[0] , image_size[1],1])
# y1 first output, to fit
W_conv = weight_variable([1, 1, 1, labels_count])
b_conv = bias_variable([labels_count])

y1 = conv2d(image, W_conv) + b_conv

cross_entropy1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(y1, y1_))
train_step1 =\
tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cross_entropy)
# Then use as input the folowing
im_y1 = tf.zeros_initializer([None,image_size[0] , image_size[1],2])
im_y1[:,:,:,0]=x
im_y1[:,:,:,1]=y1
```

The thing is to minimise first minimise cross_entropy( y1 y1_) with parameters W_conv b_conv then use y1 as parameter by construciting im_y1 as describe.

But like I written it, it dosent work because tf.zeros_initializer refuse to get the argument None.

What is the good way to pipeline different fit in the same model in Tensorflow?

Thanks to any comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the last three lines of your example with:

```
im_y1 = tf.concat(3, [x, y1])
```

It concatenates `x` and `y1` along 3-rd (0 based) dimension.

Comment: It is perfectly what I want, it seems I didn't look enough for it in the API, thank you!